# Where in Boston should I head on the Fourth of July?

Tags: public-holidays, boston

I am flying into Boston on Monday night from Australia and I am wondering where I should head to enjoy the festive spirit. Boston was the site of the early part of the Revolutionary War, so battlefields or other monuments to the Revolution would be most in keeping with the holiday.

I am staying at Copley place so sights around there would be best.

Comment: This question isn't really a good fit for the site.  Check out the blog posts that are linked to in the sidebar [on this page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta) that explain this.

Comment: @tobes: I made a change to your question that I believe can get it reopened. Are you ok with it?

Comment: I have narrowed the question to focus on "Patriotic" (Revolutionary War) sites and voted to reopen the question in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

Last year, we spent a brilliant time with Manny in the Boston YHA - he did a huge meal for all his guests and took donations for charity.

Other than that, we went for a wander around the town and *nothing* was open. If you plan to drink some beer, buy some the day before as - again - none of the shops are open :)

Answer (score 1):

Head down to the Charles river (between the Longfellow bridge and Massachusetts ave). They let off fireworks from a barge in the middle. On the banks of the river you will find a couple of million people partying. But bear in mind that drinking alcohol in public is super illegal here. So don't turn up with a box of beer.